# User Profile Sync running, but data not updated?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, forefront

Our User Profile Sync says it's working, but it's only synchronising data if I run a FULL import. Below the Sync Service telling me it's detected an update for the DS_DELTAIMPORT Profile, however the "Job Title" field isn't being set.

I notice the change doesn't appear in the subsequent MOSS_EXPORT (but may appear in MOSS_DETLASYNC, too many items to check) - does this mean it's come into ForeFront but hasn't updated SharePoint?

[image]
[image]

The Job Title field is configured to be sync'd: 
[image]

I note there's this article: Update to User Profile Property in SharePoint is not reverted to original AD value after Incremental Profile Import http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2807494

...but I haven't modified the data for this. If I had, how would I fix it?

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Is the property or the mapping newly made? Because, if so you will need to do a full sync

Comment: @RobertLindgren No, the mapping is just the default value (and I ran a full yesterday).

Comment: Check if you have set proper permission on metadata store [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj683106.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by refreshing the `Container` in the `Synchronization Connection` - basically I un-ticked the grandparent container and re-ticked it (the actual "TestAccount4" above was already selected, but it seemed to just need a refresh).

Comment: PeterX when you say refresh the containter, does this mean you need to refresh the container within AD? Thanks!

Comment: Not, not within AD, just untick/re-tick the OU's in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the Sync account with Replicating Directory Changes correctly in AD? Without this incremental changes will not be picked up. Check [articles](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) for detailed setup and container permissions in AD. The article is for 2010 but works for 2013 as well.

Comment: Yes I have. We have a new SharePoint 2013 farm running (ready for future migration) and the incremental sync works fine - the accounts used are the same.